# How to pass a list as a function's arguments

Tags: python, python-2.x

If I have a function:

```
def run(time, message, time_span_pattern):
    ...
```

And a list like:

```
run_args = ['1s', '1 second alarm', <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x100435680>]
```

How can I pass the list, as separate arguments, to run? Is there a builtin way to do this, or am I forced to reference each element individually and by index?

Comment: note, that is not a valid list because <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x100435680> is not a valid identifer. But if it had been all you need is 

    run(*run_args)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters

Comment: @e4c5 why does it work in the REPL?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski yeah but that question is about how to make a function which accepts multiple arguments, not about how to pass a list into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
run(*run_args)
```

This is explained in more detail in [this StackOverflow answer about the star and double star operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/1220089)

It's also covered in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)